# AngularJS $http promise exception not bubbling up

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an issue with an `$http` Promise not being bubbled up from the service where it is being executed to any place where the service method is called.

I have an `.authozire()` method in the service that returns the `$http` Promise, as follows:

```
// auth.service.js

function authorize(authParams) {
  var request = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: _apiUrl + 'oauth/token',
    data: authParams
  };

  return $http(request)
    .then(
      function successHandler(response) {
        // Correctly executed when success
        $log.debug('authService :: authorize => success', response);
      },
      function errorHandler(response) {
        // Correctly executed when error
        $log.debug('authService :: authorize => error', response);
      }
    );
}
```

The `success` and `error` methods above (please not that I'm already not using the `.success()` and `.error()` methods as they are deprecated) work just fine in each case, but it doesn't work as expected when I call this method from a controller, like this:

```
// signin.controller.js

function submit() {
  authService.authorize(vm.formData)
    .then(
      function successHandler(response) {
        // Always executed even when there's an error
        $log.debug('SignInController :: submit :: authService.authorize() => success', response);
      },
      function errorHandler(response) {
        // NEVER executed
        $log.debug('SignInController :: submit :: authService.authorize() => error', response);
      }
    );
}
```

The first method `successHandler` is always called, even when there's an error and the service executed its own `errorHandler`.

It seems like the Promise being returned by the service it's just a simple Promise that accepts `.then()`, but doesn't differentiate `success` and `fail` like explained in the docs:

> Returns a [Promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) that will be resolved to a response object when the request succeeds or fails.

So... Am I missing something? Does anyone had a problem like this before?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you definitely attaching it to the object returned in the service? i.e. var service = {}; service.submit = submit;

Comment: @Katana24: Yes, everything is attached as necessary and being executed just fine, except for when there's an error. In the **service**: `service = {authorize: authorise}; return service;` and in the **controller**: `vm.submit = submit;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you have a similar feeling I had when I was getting to know promises.  Here is an answer to a question I posed that was similar to yours. I was just suprised that the error wasn't propogating. [Using Kris Kowal's Q. How should I catch if any errors have been thrown throughout the life of a chained promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123202/using-kris-kowals-q-how-should-i-catch-if-any-errors-have-been-thrown-througho#23130627)

To quote that answer:

> A handled rejection is like a caught exception. It stops propagating
>   since well, it was handled. If you want to handle the rejection and
>   keep it rejected you need to rethrow, again, just like in synchronous
>   code.

```
try {
   throw new Error();
} catch(e){
    // handle error   
}
// no error here this code will keep running.
```

> If you want it to keep rejecting and handle it, you need to rethrow:

```
try {
   throw new Error();
} catch(e){
    // handle error   
    throw e;
}
// this code will not run
```

> The same with promises, just like you wrote. This is not particularly
>   odd about promises, this is how synchronous exceptions work as well.
>   If you want to propagate - you re-throw, otherwise - the errors are
>   considered handled.

1. So you can continue logging the error in your service and throw the same error you received for the next part in the chain by adding `return $q.reject(response);` in your service. You could also just say `throw response;` at the end of your service as well without the return and it will carry the error to the next part of the chain.
2. You can decide not to log the error in your service and handle it straight in your controller.

I'd personally go with 1, but that's because I can't stand when promises aren't logging their errors it's just hard to track down what's breaking without the logging.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I think that I was so used to how it worked with `.success()` and `.erro()` that I forgot how promises work 

Also, it is necessary to `return response.data` on the `successHandler` if you need it on the controller.

Comment: Yes. They are very similar in some aspects to their synchronous counter-parts try catch, it's very hard to know how everything is supposed to work when learning new concepts. Yeah, my intention was that you could `throw response;` in the catching part of your service if you get what I'm saying

Comment: Funny thing is that this is not a new concept for me, I just simply ignored them since I was expecting something else to happen. But it was good to open the mind a bit. 

Answer (score 4):

In `auth.service.js` errorHandler must return rejected promise:

```
return $q.reject(response);
```

Comment: Your solution worked, but before I accept it, would you mind explaining why? Did something change? Because it used to work like this before. Angular just automatically passed the Promise the way it was and it could be treated up in the chain.

Comment: `errorHandler` as `successHandler` returns just promise which can resolved successfuly or rejected. See @John answer for details, and you can accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are already dealing with callbacks of promise in your authentication service.

To resolve this issue we have two possible solutions:

Inside authorize method create a promise and return it.

```
function authorize(params) {
   // create a promise object
   var dfd = $q.defer();

   var request = []; // request params here

   $http(request).then(
   function SuccessHandler(res) {
      def.resolve(res);
   }, 
   function ErrorHandler(res) {
      dfd.reject(res);
   });

   return dfd.promise();
}
```

Another way is to send the http object without treating callbacks within the method authorize

```
return $http(request);
```